# Does lack of shader C compatibility matter?

Tags: c++, ios, constructor, metal

I'm going through [Up and Running with Metal, Part 2](http://metalbyexample.com/up-and-running-2/), trying to learn to rewrite all of the code using the best available language features. One of these features is a C++ constructor, which I am very happy to be able to use in my shaders, coming from Cg and GLSL, which lacked this.

This code runs fine on the device, but I get a warning:

> 'vertex_main' has C-linkage specified, but returns user-defined type
>   'ColoredVertex' which is incompatible with C

Does that matter? I don't know why C-linkage is specified. I also don't know how to disable the warning, which is what I'd like to do, along with reporting a bug, if it doesn't matter.

```
using namespace metal;

struct ColoredVertex {
    const float4 position [[position]];
    const half4 color;

    ColoredVertex(const float4 position, const half4 color)
    : position(position), color(color) {}
};

vertex ColoredVertex vertex_main(
    constant float4 *position [[buffer(0)]],
    constant float4 *color [[buffer(1)]],
    uint vid [[vertex_id]]
) {return ColoredVertex(position[vid], half4(color[vid]));}

fragment half4 fragment_main(ColoredVertex vert [[stage_in]]) {
    return vert.color;
}
```

Comment: @Deduplicator I rolled back your edit. The question is about C. Look at the warning.

Comment: No, it isn't. It's about linkage, but still a C++ question.

Comment: It says right in the warning, "C". The shader is not written in C++. It's written in Metal, hence the tag.

Comment: As I said, it's about linkage, not about C. And the warning complains about the prototype not being compatible with the selected linkage.

Comment: The question looks more related to C++ and C linkage, and your code definitely is not in C.  It does not look like C++ either... what language is it?

Comment: @Jessy Why would making use of the C++ constructor be preferable with Shaders? Thanks.

Comment: @Unheilig I think the biggest benefits of constructors are their power to enable immutability and ensure that the struct is fully-formed. (This is not shader-specific, and the benefits may not be obvious with such a small program.) A current drawback of constructors in Metal/C++ seems to be an inability to use external parameter names; hopefully this will be added later.

Comment: @Jessy If it's not too much to ask (sorry), I would like to know, how can the constructor ensure the struct is fully-formed and without the use of it, isn't? And why it might not be obvious for such a small program? Thanks again.

Comment: Sounds like a good conversation to have; let's have it in a more appropriate place, where we can be the ones deleting rude comments, instead of having ours deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's add one more function to your Metal source code:

```
int myFunction(int x) { return x / 2; }
```

And then let's run the compiler by hand and ask it to emit a human-readable format:

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos metal MyLibrary.metal -S -emit-llvm
```

The output is in `MyLibrary.ll`. Here's the definition of `vertex_main` in the output:

```
define %struct.ColoredVertex.packed @vertex_main(<4 x float> addrspace(2)* nocapture readonly, <4 x float> addrspace(2)* nocapture readonly, i32) local_unnamed_addr #1 {
  %4 = zext i32 %2 to i64
  %5 = getelementptr inbounds <4 x float>, <4 x float> addrspace(2)* %0, i64 %4
  %6 = load <4 x float>, <4 x float> addrspace(2)* %5, align 16, !tbaa !22
  %7 = getelementptr inbounds <4 x float>, <4 x float> addrspace(2)* %1, i64 %4
  %8 = load <4 x float>, <4 x float> addrspace(2)* %7, align 16, !tbaa !22
  %9 = tail call fast <4 x half> @air.convert.f.v4f16.f.v4f32(<4 x float> %8)
  %10 = insertvalue %struct.ColoredVertex.packed undef, <4 x float> %6, 0
  %11 = insertvalue %struct.ColoredVertex.packed %10, <4 x half> %9, 1
  ret %struct.ColoredVertex.packed %11
}
```

And here's the definition of `myFunction`:

```
define i32 @_Z10myFunctioni(i32) local_unnamed_addr #0 {
  %2 = sdiv i32 %0, 2
  ret i32 %2
}
```

The important thing to notice here is that the name `myFunction` got mangled, which means it has C++-linkage, while the name `vertex_main` did not get mangled, which means it has C-linkage. So we can deduce that declaring a function to be `vertex` automatically gives it C-linkage. (`fragment_main` is also unmangled.)

It's probably given C-linkage because an unmangled name is easier to look up at runtime. (Recall that we look up shader functions by name at runtime using `-[MTLLibrary newFunctionWithName:]`.)

I would guess the “incompatible with C” warning doesn't matter in your case. I think `ColoredVertex` is “incompatible with C” because it has a non-trivial constructor, but aside from that it's a C-compatible POD (plain-old data type).